# Бесконечная перезагрузка браузера при location.reload

Tags: javascript, drupal, webbrowser

В скрипте, при изменении размера окна браузера, перезагрузка выполняться бесконечно. Как ограничить выполнение скрипта только изменениями размера браузера?

Возможно ли что проблема не в коде, а связана с моим сайтом? Я использую Drupal, и использую этот код в шаблоне. Так вот проблема появляется после первой перезагрузки, дальше идет бесконечная перезагрузка. Если почистить кеш в админке друпала, то ошибка (бесконечная перезагрузка) пропадает. Ровно до следующего изменения размера браузера.

вот пример кода:

```js
<script>
$(window).resize(function(){
window.setTimeout('location.reload()', 500);
});
</script>
```

P.S. нашел в интернете другие варианты кода, проблема та же...

Comment: зачем вы вообще используете такое?

Comment: таймаут не причем, я пробовал разные варианты. перезагрузка идет автоматом бесконечно

Comment: какой браузер используется?

Comment: @VladimirNovopashin задача в том, что когда пользователь изменяет размеры браузера, нужно чтобы верстка пришла в норму. Если он сузит браузер, а потом снова расширит, то элементы не становятся на места, наверное из-за css свойства: auto  для этого и нужна перезагрузка страницы.  Если у вас есть совет как по-другому сделать, то подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: посмотри css я написал как под это настроить

Comment: Перезагрузка страницы при изменении размера окна - это в корне неправильно. Весь контент на сайте должен быть "резиновым". Если при расширении окна контент не приходит в норму - здесь уже встает вопрос а каким образом вы уменьшаете контент?

Answer (score -2):

Правильно это делается так:

Только javascript:

```
window.onresize = function(){ location.reload(); }
```

С jquery:

```
$(window).resize(function(){location.reload();});
```

Или:

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){location.reload();});
```

Другие варианты:

1. Попробуйте открыть в другом браузере
2. Убрать функцию
3. Открыть сайт с другого устройства
4. Настроить CSS

CSS:

```
html, body, {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Comment: Непонятно, чем второй вариант с jquery принципиально отличается от кода в вопросе

Comment: Насколько я знаю js, он в данном случае вроде не играет никакой существенной роли

Comment: спасибо за участие! Проверил, в других браузерах все норм. Только в Хроме идет бесконечная перезагрузка! И возможно в сафари, нет возможности протестировать.  Может кто подскажет почему? и как исправить?

Comment: сначала продебагировать, либо в лоб, попробуй css, посмотри оптимизацию веб приложения под хром, конкретно для своего случая и своих `друпала` и что ты тым еще используешь

Comment: вообщем покопал еще глубже. Проблема есть только когда юзер залогинен как админ. Для анонимов все окей. возможно это связано с css (у админа доп меню сверху), или как-то связано с кешем для админа.. вообщем что-то заставляет браузер вести себя по-другому. Напоминаю, когда почистишь кеш из админки, то бесконечная перезагрузка превращается.

Comment: пробовал создать другого пользователя?

Comment: @PauloBerezini да. Проблема только с админом. Вот только непонятно это кэш влияет. Или из-за верстки

Comment: @AlexSorokin попробуй пересобрать проект